# Ruby class key based on other keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slug

I have the following ruby class:

```
class Question
key :id, String
key :data, String, :default => "", :required => true
```

I would like to add another key that is based off of id and title (specifically "#{id} #{data}"). Is there an easy way to do this.

The reason I need this is because I am using mongo map slugizer which wants the name of a key to slugize (its code calls `slugize(self[key_provided]))` I am trying to figure out how to use it to slugize the id + data together without having to change its code.  Any ideas?

Edit:
I am using slugizer from mongomapper_ext. you can see from the following example: https://github.com/dcu/mongomapper_ext/blob/master/examples/slugizer.rb

that slug_key is passed the name of one of the keys in which to slugize. i would like to define two keys to slugize together, without having to change their code. Thanks!

Comment: this class can't works like that. What is this Object. ActiveRecord::Base, Mongoid::Document, DataMapper ?

Comment: can you provide more context / code here?  where does that key method come from?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where the key :xx comes from but to have your class respond to arbitrary function calls such as Question.1ABRA you should use **method_missing** functionality as long as "#{id}#{data}" is can be detected by a regular exception

http://kconrails.com/2010/12/21/dynamic-methods-in-ruby-with-method_missing/